# Append ajax result to a select 2 multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i need to append to a select2 multiple, some results fetched from ajax. I try to achieve this result using this code:

```
<select name='prodotti' rows='5' multiple id='prodotti' class='select2'></select>
```

Here is JS

```
$('#close-modal').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = $('#id').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/items-fattura?id=' + id,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#prodotti").val(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Ajax return this results:

```
[{"id":2,"nome":"Certificato SSL POSITIVE"}]
```

Can someone help me to resolve?

Comment: Resolve what? What results are you expecting?

Comment: You are using select2 plugin or simple select HTML element ??

Comment: You want to append option or set value

Comment: Both, using select2 append value and set text

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/items-fattura?id=' + id,
    success: function (response) {

        var $el = $("#prodotti");

        $el.empty(); // remove old options

        $el.append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", 0)
                .text('Select'));

        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

            $el.append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", response[i]['id'])
                    .text(response[i]['name']));
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **<kbd>[$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)</kbd>** to iterate through your JSON array that you receive from ajax call.

Note:- the spelling of `success`, you have written `sucess`.

```
 success: function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        var toAppend = '';
        $('#prodotti').empty();
        $.each(data, function(i,o){
           toAppend += '<option value="'+ o.nome +'">'+o.id+'</option>';
        });
         $('#prodotti').append(toAppend);
  }
```

Comment: thanks this working as well but i'm not sufficient clear in request i need that the fetched value coming as option selected. How i can mark it as selected?

Answer (score 0):

If you receiving multiple values that are separated by comma, you can use this `select2` trick to set the values:

```
var makeArray = commanSeparatedValues.split(',');
$('#SELECT_ID').val(makeArray);
```

It's an nifty little cool trick that you should use when working with `select2`. Avoiding the loops and `$.each`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at
https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items
for adding options to a select2 by js